# How to count rows in mysql subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables course and registered_course

course table

| crid | crname | crlevel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | math | senior |
| 2 | english | senior |
| 3 | physics | senior |

Registered course table

| id | crid | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 2 | 26 |
| 3 | 3 | 23 |
| 4 | 3 | 24 |
| 5 | 3 | 27 |

so i want to achieved this result the first table join with second table and a count of students that registered a subject just like below thanks

| crname | crlevel | number_of_student |
| --- | --- | --- |
| math | senior | 2 |
| physic | senior | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.crname, table1.crlevel, count(table2.studentid)
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.crid = table2.crid
GROUP BY table1.crname, table1.crlevel
```